# How can I get the request.login method working with a jdbcRealm?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, glassfish-3, jaas

I am trying to use the Servlet 3.0 request.login(username, password) method to work with a jdbcRealm, but something seems to be wrong.  There are many articles out there on how to get the jdbcRealm working with FORM authentication, and lots on how to use the new request.login method, but I haven't seen any that show both working together.

Application Server - GlassFish 3.1.2
IDE - Netbeans 7.3
RDBMS - SQL Server 2008 R2
JDBC - Microsoft JDBC 4.0 driver

I'd appreciate some assistance from the community on how to get this working.  Thanks in advance!

First, I'm sending a jquery ajax call into my SignInService servlet.  I'm encoding the password using the jsSHA library in SHA-512 before sending:

```
var encodedPassword = new jsSHA($("#omSignInPassword").val(), "TEXT");

$.ajax({
      url: "SignInService",
      data: {
        username : $("#SignInUserName").val(),
        password : encodedPassword.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX")
      }
...
});
```

This is what Chrome shows is being sent:

```
username:admin
password:b109f3bbbc244eb82441917ed06d618b9008dd09b3befd1b5e07394c706a8bb980b1d7785e5976ec049b46df5f1326af5a2ea6d103fd07c95385ffab0cacbc86
```

The servlet just takes the request parameters and tries to log in:

```
  username = request.getParameter(PARAM_USERNAME);
  password = request.getParameter(PARAM_PASSWORD);

  request.login(username, password);
```

These are the errors that I see in the GlassFish console:

SEVERE: jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
SEVERE: Servlet Exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception thrown while attempting to authenticate for user: admin
WARNING: DPL5032:An authentication method was not defined in the web.xml descriptor.  Using default BASIC for login configuration.
WARNING: No Principals mapped to Role [User].

Now, on to the configuration...

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <login-config>
        <realm-name>omRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

User Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [OM_SECURITY].[User](
    [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [char](128) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](64) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

One record exists in this table:

```
1   admin   B109F3BBBC244EB82441917ED06D618B9008DD09B3BEFD1B5E07394C706A8BB980B1D7785E5976EC049B46DF5F1326AF5A2EA6D103FD07C95385FFAB0CACBC86    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

(the password is just "password" for now)

Here is the View used for putting every user into the "User" group.  This is very basic and will change later once I have the core functionality in place.  I do not anticipate using JAAS Roles as my application requirements seem to be far more complex than what they provide.  That's probably another discussion, unless somehow this is impacting the authentication:

```
CREATE VIEW [OM_SECURITY].[SignInGroup]
AS
SELECT     'User' AS GroupName, Name AS UserName
FROM         OM_SECURITY.[User]
```

The connection pool has been tested and it works just fine. The Realm was set up in the server-config section and not the default-config.

```
JAAS Context:  jdbcRealm
JNDI:  jdbc/omSecurity
User Table:  OM_SECURITY.User
User Name Column:  Name
Password Column:  Password
Group Table:  OM_SECURITY.SignInGroup
Group Table User Name Column:   UserName
Group Name Column:  GroupName
Assign Groups: (blank)
Database User:  (blank)
Database Password:  (blank)
Digest Algorithm: SHA-512
Password Encryption Algorithm:  AES
Encoding: Hex
Charset: (blank)
```

If someone can tell me what file stores the Realm and Connection Pool configuration I'll post those here as XML instead.

This was also posted to the GlassFish forum here:

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish-webtier/using-servlet-requestlogin-jdbcrealm

Update: I have just put together a quick form based login and it is also failing, so the issue seems to be with my realm.  I adjusted the log level for  in:

Configurations\
server-config\
Logging\
Log Levels\

javax.enterprise.system.core.security = FINE

AND

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc = FINE

The query is running fine according to SQL Server, there are no exceptions thrown from the Connection Pool:

```
FINE: SQLServerPreparedStatement:3: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:SELECT Password FROM omUser WHERE Name = @P0
```

Comment: checkout this tutorial http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/securing-java-ee-6-web-applications-on-glassfish-using-jaas

Comment: If that was an answer I would mark it "correct"

Answer (score 4):

You're logging in with

```
username = request.getParameter(PARAM_USERNAME);
password = request.getParameter(PARAM_PASSWORD);
request.login(username, password);
```

where password is already hashed. I believe that request.login() takes the plain text version, which the container then compares to the hashed version in the database.

As a side note, it is generally considered bad practice to hash the password at the client, it should be sent as plain text through ssl. The hashing (+salt) in your database is used to prevent a hacker from being able to log in as as another user if they compromised your database. Storing hashed passwords prevents this, but *only* if your server accepts the plain text password. If it accepts the hashed password then they have all they need.

Comment: This is what I get when I send it through without hashing:

SEVERE: jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason  
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception  
SEVERE: Servlet Exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception thrown while attempting to authenticate for user: admin

Comment: I agree that SSL is the preferred way to send the login information.  I plan to add that once I have the core functionality working.  I just wasn't sure if I needed to match the encoding algorithm declared in the realm.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Password Encryption Algorithm field to: **none** (or leave empty & ignore the warning)?

Comment: Exact same error.  I changed the Password field to varchar(128) as well.

Comment: I have this working now with a form login, but have to note that you were very correct in saying that I shouldn't be encoding the password.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience using jdbcRealm of Glassfish,

```
request.login(username, password);
```

password here should contain the plain password entered by the user and not the hashed one because that is the job of the jdbcRealm. That would explain why you get an authentication error since the hashed password you used as value for the password will still be hashed based on the realm configuration.

Here is my jdbcRealm configuration last time I did this:

```
Password Encryption Algorithm: SHA-256
Digest Algorithm: SHA-256
Charset: UTF-8
```